# PowerTools Beta 3 fails

Tags: entity-framework, ef-power-tools

I was trying to generate "views" to enhance the performance of my application. The application is Silverlight 4 linked with RIA services to the Server. The server application started with EF 4.1 + RIA Services. 
I installed "EF Power Tools Beta 3 v0.7.0.0" and could generate my views with no problem. But I soon realized that EF 4.1. was not able to benefit from the precompiled views. EF >= 4.2 was required.
Through NuGet I saw an update for RIA Services (RIAServices.EntityFramework.4.2.0) which used EF 5. I installed and got everything working but when I try to generate views I get an exception:

`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`

I've tried reinstalling PowerTools. No luck
I've downloaded source code for PowerTools and debugged the Exception. Apparently PowerTools was trying and could not find the old EF version. The LoaderExceptions property read:

`{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.`

I've investigated the PublicKeyToken and confirmed that it is the same as the EF 5 (EF 4.4 target=.NET 4) dll found in my "bin" output map. But PowerTools is looking for EF 4.1.. why?

My web.config file has this:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
  <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

and:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I've also tested changing the PublicKeyToken in Web.config just to confirm that I get another error from PowerTools thus PowerTools seems to parse my Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I've created a new Web project and added all Model code files as links. Same connectionstrings. Now i can build views.. strange.. same references.

When I add the views to my original project the RIA services won't start. Removed views and they started again.